# Objective C : How to extract a path from CaShapeLayer

Tags: objective-c, path, cashapelayer

I have a CAShapeLayer as a parameter of a method and need to it's related Path. Can anyone advise?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: CAShapeLayer has CGPathRef path property. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CAShapeLayer` has the following property:

```
@property CGPathRef path;
```

...which will return you the path associated with the layer.